# Toggle VideoView's audio with a Button

Tags: java, android, audio

I am using a videoView to play a video.

```
 bVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.bVideoView);
 bVideoView.setVideoPath(videoPath);
```

Now I have a button,

```
audioToggle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.audioToggle);
```

Then I have the Button's `OnClickListener`

```
private static int aux = 0;
private AudioManager mAudioManager;

 audioToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                bVideoView.start();

                mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                if(aux % 2 == 0){

                    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 50, 0);
                    aux++;

                } else {

                    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
                    aux++;

                }
            }
        });
```

Now with this `OnClickListener` I am perfectly able to toggle the audio to mute and unmute when it is clicked each time. However I want something like this,

1. On the first click the videoView should start.
2. When I keep pressing the button the audio must mute.
3. When I release the button the audio must unmute.

I have been trying a lot and failing in some or the other way. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

> 1. The first time I hold the button,  the video should play.
> 2. While I'm holding the button the audio must be heard.
> 3. When I **release** the button, the audio must be muted.
> 4. When I **press and hold** the button again, the audio must be heard again.

Then what you therefore need is not an `OnClickListener` but rather an `OnTouchListener`

What happens under the hood is that your `OnClickListener` is always called after you release your finger. Using `View.OnTouchListener` you can dispatch events when you press (you mean touch and hold) and release.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Here's a sample snippet:

```
private static int aux = 0;
private AudioManager mAudioManager;

audioToggle.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

        bVideoView.start();

        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        switch(e.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 50, 0);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally, I don't recommend controlling the system's volume. Use a `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener` instead, get the `VideoView`’s `MediaPlayer` and then play around with its volume.

### Edit:

Here's another sample snippet:

```
private MediaPlayer bVideoViewMP;


bVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // Fetch a reference
        bVideoViewMP = mp;
    }
});

audioToggle.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

        bVideoView.start();

        switch(e.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                bVideoViewMP.setVolume(0.75f, 0.75f);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                bVideoViewMP.setVolume(0, 0);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

These should be placed either on your fragment's `onViewCreated()` or on your activity's `onCreate()` method before the `VideoView` has been fully prepared.

Comment: Ya that is what I also though, can you suggest me how to do that ?